# Django setting up profile page for viewing

Tags: django, user-profile

How would one go about creating a user-profile page that other users can view without being able to edit the profile unless they are the user?

The thing I'm trying to work out is how the url routing would work, is it best practice to store a user's profile on a `profile/<username> or <user_id>` page and then load in the individual user's data like recent posts using the username or id passed through the url?

Also would this be handled by the one view and template and just use `{% if request.user == profile.user %}` to display things like edit profile etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proposed solution is the simplest way of going about it. It will meet all your requirements and its only downside is the need for mixing read-only and edit code in one template.

Other option would be to have `profile/username` be read-only view and having `profile/<username>/edit` for editing (obviously restricted to just the owner).